# How to Solve Out of Memory exception error when loading data to HTML Table

Tags: c#-4.0, linq-to-sql

I have HTML Table which i am using to populate the data from the table, the database table contains more 50000 rows and it throws an error "Out of Memory exception error". If i have used a where clause and select few rows and it works which is not how it should work. Please Help. Thanks!

Here is my code.

```
    protected void PopulatePage()
    {
        try
        {
                RepeaterBankStatement.DataSource = _dc.SelectBankStatement().ToList();
                RepeaterBankStatement.DataBind(); // Out of Memory exception

        }
        catch(Exception EX)
        {

        }
    }
```

This code works fine if i have used where clause but i don't want to use where clause. i want it to populate all the records.

```
    protected void PopulatePage()
    {
        try
        {
                RepeaterBankStatement.DataSource = _dc.SelectBankStatement().Where(m => m.Description3 == "12345678524").ToList().Take(50000);
                RepeaterBankStatement.DataBind();

        }
        catch(Exception EX)
        {

        }

    }
```

Comment: Try to remove `.ToList();` in the first code. It's unecessary.

Comment: It gaves me the same error : Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

Comment: You do not have enough memory for the full result set. In the where clause you have less results because you are filtering and taking only 50000. You need a bigger RAM

Comment: So the only solutions is to get the bigger ram? There's no other means of coding or any means which can resolve the problem? I am using 4G Ram

Answer (score 0):

You can try to minimize memory consumption to do a `select new {}` with only the data you actually need. It will also eliminate the change tracking overhead. This might reduce it just enough.

From your question it is not really clear if the repeater really shows everything at once, otherwise you can implement paging

Comment: please help me by editing from the coding cause i don't understand how to continue